# Description of Hadoop job

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have a Hadoop cluster and different processes are able submit mapreduce jobs to this cluster (they all use the same user account).

Is there a way to distinguish these jobs?  Some kind of description, which can be added to job during submit like 'This is a job of process "1234", do not touch'?

I am using Python and HadoopStreaming,  and would like to distinguish jobs using simple `hadoop job -list` (or at least using web management interface).

Comment: Are you using Amazon's EMR?

Comment: @Amar, Nope, just regular Python

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify a name for each job using `job.setJobName(String)`.

If you were to set the job name to something distinguishing you should be able to tell them apart.

For example, by using something like`ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()` you can get the process id and machine name (on linux anyway, unsure of behaviour on other operating systems) in the format of `1234@localhost`, where `1234` is the process id, which you could set to the job name to tell them apart.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using Python and don't have access to Java API.  I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

For a cross-compatible solution, you can always use the `mapred.job.name` to specify the name of your job, which should allow you to easily distinguish everything with `hadoop job -list` later on.

In case of Hadoop streaming this should look something like this:

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_STREAMING_JAR -Dmapred.job.name='something' -mapper mapper.py -reducer reducer.py -input /path/to/input -output /path/to/output
```